# Why does conditional variable assignment set a value but standard assignment does not?

Tags: gnu-make

For the purposes of this question, by conditional variable assignment I meant the `?=` operator and standard assignment I mean the `:=` operator.

I am trying to check whether a command exists by assigning it to a variable and then checking it using `ifdef` but I am seeing differing behaviour depending on which of the two operators I use to do the initial assignment.

Here is a distilled Makefile example. Note that neither `foo` nor `bar` exist on my system and so I would expect both checks to trigger the "not found" branches.

```
FOO := $(shell which foo)
BAR ?= $(shell which bar)

all:
ifdef FOO
    echo "FOO found with value '${FOO}'"
else
    echo "FOO not found"
endif
ifdef BAR
    echo "BAR found with value '${BAR}'"
else
    echo "BAR not found"
endif
```

When I run `make`, I get this result:

```
FOO not found
BAR found with value ''
```

The [GNU make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Syntax) says that `ifdef` looks for a non-empty value.

Why do these two assignment operators differ in their behaviour and what they produce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consult the [GNU Make documentation](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html) to note the difference between
a *recursively expanded variable* and a *simply expanded variable*.

```
FOO := $(shell which foo)
```

defines `FOO` with the simply expanded value of `$(shell which foo)`,
which is the empty string. Hence `ifdef FOO` will evaluate false.

```
BAR ?= $(shell which bar)
```

defines BAR, unless it is already defined, as `$(shell which bar)`. It abbreviates

```
ifndef BAR
    BAR = $(shell which bar)
endif
```

Notice `=`, not `:=`

Assuming `BAR` was not already defined, its definition becomes `$(shell which bar)`, not the empty string.
Thus in:

```
ifdef BAR
    echo "BAR found with value '${BAR}'"
else
    echo "BAR not found"
endif
```

`BAR` is found to have a definition and the recursively expanded value of
its definition is echoed, which is ''.

To get the same behaviour from `BAR` as from `FOO`, try:

```
FOO := $(shell which foo)
BAR ?= $(shell which bar)
BAR := $(BAR)

all:
ifdef FOO
    echo "FOO found with value '${FOO}'"
else
    echo "FOO not found"
endif
ifdef BAR
    echo "BAR found with value '${BAR}'"
else
    echo "BAR not found"
endif
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks for the explanation. I think I have only ever encountered simply expanded variables before which is why this behaviour confused me.